# Multiple Stop Losses in Pine Script

Tags: pine-script, trading, tradingview-api

I have a trading strategy in Pine Script that has multiple open positions at any given time. I am trying to set up a separate stop loss for each position, but am having trouble with the results I'm getting. My script seems to be working on the most recent position, but the stop loss isn't being calculated properly for older positions. My assumption is that the value is being repainted, but I can't figure out a way around it. I've tried using arrays as well to save the stop loss value, but I could use some help if that is the right way to go about it.

Any advice or alternate methods would be very helpful!!

Thanks.

```
    //@version=5
strategy("DIBS SELL", overlay=true, pyramiding=1000)


// Start date of strategy
startHour = input.int(title="Start Hour", defval=14, minval=0, maxval=23)
startDate = input.int(title="Start Date", defval=14, minval=1, maxval=31)
startMonth = input.int(title="Start Month", defval=7, minval=1, maxval=12)
startYear = input.int(title="Start Year", defval=2022, minval=1800, maxval=2100)


// See if this bar's time happened on/after start date
afterStartDate = (time >= timestamp(syminfo.timezone,
     startYear, startMonth, startDate, startHour, 0))



// Session for trade to execute
session = input("0000-1630,1830-0000:1234567")
t = time(timeframe.period, session)


// Pair currently being traded
pair = syminfo.basecurrency + "/" + syminfo.currency


// Condition
insideBar = high < high[1] and low > low[1]
prevInsideBar = ta.barssince(insideBar)


// Entry point
sellPoint = low - (1 * 10 * syminfo.mintick)
sellStopLoss = ((high[(bar_index - strategy.opentrades.entry_bar_index(strategy.opentrades - 1)) + 1] - (strategy.opentrades.entry_price(strategy.opentrades - 1))) / syminfo.mintick)
sellStopLossAlert = high + (2 * 10 * syminfo.mintick)
sellTakeProfit = ((high[(bar_index - strategy.opentrades.entry_bar_index(strategy.opentrades - 1)) + 1] - (strategy.opentrades.entry_price(strategy.opentrades - 1))) / syminfo.mintick) + 20
sellTakeProfitAlert = sellPoint - (sellStopLossAlert - sellPoint) - (2 * 10 * syminfo.mintick)


// Quantity calculation
quantity = 100 - strategy.opentrades
quantityAdd = 100 - strategy.opentrades - 1
quantityAbove = 91 + strategy.opentrades + 1
quantityAddAbove = 91 + strategy.opentrades
qtyStopLoss = strategy.opentrades.size(strategy.opentrades)
qtyTakeProfit = strategy.opentrades.size(strategy.opentrades)


// Alert message
msg_sell = 'q=' + str.tostring(quantity) + ' fsl=' + str.tostring(sellStopLossAlert) + ' e=oandapractice' + ' s=' + str.tostring(pair) + ' b=short' + ' t=market' + ' a=SUBSELL'
msg_sell_add = 'q=' + str.tostring(quantityAdd) + ' fsl=' + str.tostring(sellStopLossAlert) + ' ftp=' + str.tostring(sellTakeProfitAlert) + ' e=oandapractice' + ' s=' + str.tostring(pair) + ' b=short' + ' t=market' + ' a=SUBSELL'


// Entry ID
tradeID = str.tostring(strategy.opentrades + strategy.closedtrades)
tradeIDAdd = str.tostring(strategy.opentrades + strategy.closedtrades + 1)


// Entry
if insideBar and afterStartDate and not na(t)
    if strategy.opentrades > 10
        strategy.entry(tradeID, strategy.short, qty=quantityAbove, stop=sellPoint, alert_message=msg_sell)
        strategy.entry(tradeIDAdd, strategy.short, qty=quantityAddAbove, stop=sellPoint, alert_message=msg_sell_add)
    else
        strategy.entry(tradeID, strategy.short, qty=quantity, stop=sellPoint, alert_message=msg_sell)
        strategy.entry(tradeIDAdd, strategy.short, qty=quantityAdd, stop=sellPoint, alert_message=msg_sell_add) 



// Cancel open order after 1 completed candle after inside bar
if prevInsideBar == 1
    strategy.cancel_all()


// To identify inside bar candle
plotshape(insideBar, style=shape.arrowdown, color=color.white)


// Plot session
bgcolor(not na(t) ? color.new(color.green, 90) : na)



// Array
sellStop = high[1] + (2 * 10 * syminfo.mintick)

var label _label = na

var float [] LABELARRAY = array.new_float()

if bar_index and prevInsideBar == 1 and strategy.opentrades > strategy.opentrades[1]
    array.push(LABELARRAY, sellStop)


// Stop Loss
strategy.exit("Short Exit", from_entry=strategy.opentrades.entry_id(strategy.opentrades), qty=qtyStopLoss, loss=sellStopLoss)
```

I've also attached an image below that shows what the stop loss (yellow line) should be for the first position. As you can see in the screenshot the value is being changed.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nY3YL.png)

Answer (score 0):

Yes by default, the SL/TP will be defined based on the most recent order unless you're using arrays like I did here : https://www.tradingview.com/script/Puprh5UJ-Strategy-Multiple-Orders-Statistics-Template-Educational/

In this script, I can have multiple trades per trend and each trade has its own TPs
Feel free to replicate that for your idea of multiple SLs per trade